# Show a custom web page when applicatino is stopped

Tags: tomcat

I developed a web application which is deployed in Apache Tomcat.There is a need to stop the application without stopping the Tomcat.It can be done using the start/stop functionality provided by the tomcat manger.The requirement is to display a custom web page(which say application is down for maintenance) when the web application is stopped.I want to know that is tomcat facilitate to do this by configuring the webxml in catalina/conf or by any other mechanism.Can any body give an idea.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit old question but I will add my 2 cents as it might help someone down the track.

My understanding that everything served from Tomcat comes from an application. Whenever you create a folder inside webapps, that will become available as an app.

That said, it's fairly easy to provide the functionality using an apache http in front of your tomcat server.

Using mod_proxy on apache http, when the tomcat application is down, tomcat returns a http 503. You only need to add the line below to your httpd.conf (or uncomment if it's already there) and create a downtime.html (in this case) inside your apache www folder (or htdocs). :)

```
ErrorDocument 503 /downtime.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps supply a custom error page (500 status, or whatever the server would normally return when the application is not responding), and have it just use that?

Comment: mmmmm.Once I configured the Tomcat to view the custom error page,it will be use for all the web applications deployed in the Tomcat,am I correct?If so the error page should be more generic.Any way can you explain how the Tomcat is configured to display a custom error page?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a custom page for my stopped or temporarily undeployed webapp.
First, I created a custom error page and put it in /srv/www/html/maintenance/report.html.
Then, I created a custom valve, compiled, jared and put it in tomcats (6) lib folder.

```
package my.package;

import org.apache.catalina.Container;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;

/**
* Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
* User: przemyslaw
* Date: 13.11.11
*/
public class AppErrorReportValve extends ValveBase {
  String errorPagePath = null;
  String appContextName = null;
  String appContextPath = null;

  public void invoke(Request request, Response response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    StandardContext appContext = (StandardContext)container.findChild(appContextName);

    if((appContext==null || appContext.getState()!=1 || !appContext.getAvailable()) && request.getRequestURI().startsWith(appContextPath)){
         if (response.isCommitted()) {
            return;
         }

        // The response is an error
        response.setError();

        // Reset the response (if possible)
        try {
            response.reset();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        }

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        response.setSuspended(false);

        try {
            //containerLog.info("render Error");
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            renderError(response);
            return;
        } catch (Throwable tt) {

        }


    }
    // Perform the request
    getNext().invoke(request, response);

}

void renderError(Response response){
       BufferedInputStream bis = null;
       OutputStream os = null;

       try
       {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (errorPagePath);
         bis = new BufferedInputStream (fis);
         os = response.getOutputStream();

         int byte_;
         while ((byte_ = bis.read ()) != -1)
           os.write (byte_);
       }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e)
       {
         containerLog.error("File not found " + errorPagePath, e);
         // Do other stuff related to that exception (if necessary).
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
         containerLog.error("I/O Problem: ",e);
         // Do other stuff related to that exception (if necessary).
       }
       finally
       {
         if (bis != null)
           try
           {
             bis.close ();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
           }

         if (os != null)
           try
           {
             os.flush();
             os.close ();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
           }
       }

  }

  public String getErrorPagePath() {
    return errorPagePath;
  }

  public void setErrorPagePath(String errorPagePath) {
    this.errorPagePath = errorPagePath;
  }

  public String getAppContextName() {
    return appContextName;
  }

  public void setAppContextName(String appContextName) {
    this.appContextName = appContextName;
    this.appContextPath = appContextName+"/";
  }
}
```

At least I configured tomcats conf/server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <Valve className="my.package.AppErrorReportValve" appContextName="/report" errorPagePath="/srv/www/html/maintenance/report.html" resolveHosts="false"/>
     ...
  </Host>
```

Now tomcat shows a custom service not available page, when my web app /report is stopped or undeployed.